# Is it possible to set stable key in Glide library instead of the URI or resource ID

Tags: android, android-glide

In Piccasso library there is a way to set stable key instead of the URI or resource ID.

```
Picasso.with(context).load(url).stableKey(getStableKey(url))
```

Is there a way to do the same in Glide library?

Comment: here is an issue about your question. https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/501